# A FactoryGirl factory for a many-to-many self-referenced model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I've got a self-referenced user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :following,
                            :class_name               => "User",
                            :foreign_key              => 'follower_id',
                            :association_foreign_key  => 'following_id',
                            :join_table               => 'followers'
    has_and_belongs_to_many :followers,
                            :class_name               => "User",
                            :foreign_key              => 'following_id',
                            :association_foreign_key  => 'follower_id',
                            :join_table               => 'followers'
    ...
end
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a FactoryGirl factory to test this behavior. I've tried some variations of

```
factory :user do
    ...
    factory :following do
        after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
            create_list(:user, evaluator.followers_count, follower: user)
        end
    end
end
```

but had no luck with it. How would you do this? Thanks for any input.

Comment: `networky_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, followers: [FactoryGirl.create(:user)], following: [FactoryGirl.create(:user)])`